# Issue on creating auto number field

Tags: apex, before-trigger, auto-number

I need to create an auto number field on custom object in packaging org. I'm not able to create it now because it's throwing an error while creating it:

> you cant able to create auto number field once its managed

So I created a one number field and incrementing the number by 1 whenever the record gets created through trigger. Here I am getting an issue of duplicate numbers while am creating multiple records in a single transaction, any solution for this?

Comment: When quoting messages, cut and paste them so the text is exact. Is this your problem https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6oYAAQ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error message is:

> Error: Auto number fields cannot be added to a custom object when the
>   custom object has already been uploaded in a Managed - Released
>   package.

See this option [Auto number field cannot be added into managed package object, any walkaround?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89567/auto-number-field-cannot-be-added-into-managed-package-object-any-walkaround) where a new custom object is added. The reliable auto-number from the new object can be transferred to the existing object via a trigger.

Surprisingly, I can't find an example of a trigger that does the auto-number generation avoiding duplicates programmatically. The key mechanism to achieve that though is [Locking Statements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm), where the trigger can execute a query with `for update` and so block triggers running at the same time while the increment is done.